# c++ timer to call a function/method later?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timer

I have a program in C++. I want to call a function asynchronously with a configurable wait time before.

My idea of a solutions is to create a thread and in the body I would wait for the configured time and then call the needed function and then destroy the thread again.

The overhead seams very high to me, creating a separate thread. Is there a better solution (less overhead) like a timer to call the function later?

Comment: If you want to do this asynchronously  you're going to have to spin up a thread.

Comment: While creating and tearing down a thread can be expensive, you have to think about it relatively: Will you do this very often? If not then it's no big deal, especially if the timer is long (for a computer). Otherwise perhaps keep the thread around for multiple timers?

Comment: If you're using something event-driven (like Qt or pretty much any other GUI, or something like Boost ASIO) those usually have timers you can use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your operating system.

On Windows you can use the WinAPI [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer), on Linux use [timerfd](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timerfd_create) or [timer_create](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create).

Comment: Thank you for the links. For platform dependent development they are very good. I'm looking for a platform independent solution.